# Angular project crashes due to installation any npm packages. if we install same package in test project it works but not in Actual projects

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular7, node-modules, npm-install

Both project have same **angular cli** **versions '7.2.0'** 
Its First time we are facing this issue any one know what is the next way forword to fix this situation.Here is the json file of real working project.

```
  "name": "financial-service",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

And Here is the package.json file of test project

```
  "name": "ag-grid-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.5",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^17.4.47",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7": "^0.1.5",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

All multiselect Dropdown packages are working in test project but when we run ng serve in actual project

````
Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:6
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
t\core\src\json\schema\registry.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)```[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w2vP.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a webpack issue. Follow the below steps.

1. delete node_modules in the project
2. npm cache verify
   3.npm install

For more details refer [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5469)

Comment: Can you give it a try with a different version of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

i cant find jav from your package.json and you use then inside code.
my idea is you can install again **npm install --save-dev ajv@6.5.5**
and if dont fixed your problem try to 
delete node_modules in the project
**npm cache verify**
next go on 
**npm install**

Comment: After executing the above command now this error occure```Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).```

Comment: are you sure installed ajv ?

Comment: yes i have install Ajv ...this error occure after installing Ajv